# how to access "this" in props validator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a project using nuxt.js, I'm injecting a function in the context of the application as recommended in the official documentation

**https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#inject-in-root-amp-context**

but when I try to call the function inside a props validation I get an error

`/plugins/check-props.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$checkProps = function(value, arr) {
  return arr.indexOf(value) !== -1
}
```

in a component vue

```
export default {
  props: {
    color: {
      type: String,
      validator: function (value, context) {
        this.$checkProps(value, ['success', 'danger'])
      }
  }
}
```

`ERROR:` Cannot read property '$checkProps' of undefined

Does anyone know how I can access "this" within validation?

thanks in advance!

Comment: As a general comment, the Nuxt docs weren't all that good the last time I checked, don't take their recommendations at face value. In fairness, it's been a bit since I last worked on a project with it, but I doubt they've had a major overhaul.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Props validation is done before the component is initialized, so you won't have access to `this` as you are extending `Vue.prototype`.

Form their [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation):

> Note that props are validated before a component instance is created, so instance properties (e.g. data, computed, etc) will not be available inside default or validator functions.

In general, if `$checkProps` is only used for checking the value of these props, I would just use a helper function.

```
// array.helpers.js
export function containsValue(arr, val) {
  return arr.indexOf(value) !== -1
}

// component
import { containsValue } from 'path/to/helpers/array.helpers';
props: {
    foo: {
       //
       validator(value) {
          return containsValue(['foo', 'bar'], value);
       }
    }
}
```

#### Update

Based on your comments, if you don't want to import this specific function over and over again, you can just `Array.prototype.includes` [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
// component
props: {
    color: {
       //
       validator(value) {
          return ['success', 'danger'].includes(value);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is that every time I write a validator, I'll have to import the `{containsValue} from 'array.helpers.js'`?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to import it multiple times. However if you are planning to reuse this logic in multiple components, for example a group of components that receive a color prop  `['success', 'danger']`, you use a `mixin` to extend the components you want to apply these props to. Check the [documentation on mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Comment: in fact I would like to access this function from any component, not just a group of components, I would prefer to register the function globally and so that I do not have to import it so I can use some idea?

Comment: register a function globally in nuxt.js and access within a props validation

Comment: In general, I avoid using global functions, specially for helpers like this. ES6 has functions that you can use out of the box to achieve this `['foo', 'bar'].includes(value)`

Comment: Thanks for the support, great answers!

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation):

> props are validated before a component instance is created, so
> instance properties (e.g. data, computed, etc) will not be available
> inside default or validator functions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the `nuxt` plugins you can always use the `window` object.This is how I do it to access the `i18n` library

```
{
   validator: (value: any): boolean => {
      return window.$nuxt.$te(value);
   }
}
```

In your case:

```
{
   validator: (value: any): boolean => {
      return window.$nuxt.$checkProps(value, ['success', 'danger']);
   }
}
```

In any case you should never prototype in the window object. Let `nuxt` handle it with a plugin:

path: `plugins/check-props.js` or `.ts`

```
function checkProps(value: any, arr: string[]): boolean {
  return arr.indexOf(value) !== -1
}

const $checkProps: Plugin = (_context: Context, inject: Inject) => {
  inject('checkProps', checkProps);
};

export default $checkProps;
```

And then in nuxt config

```
{
  plugins: [{ src: 'plugins/check-props.js', ssr: true }]
}
```